# Recording comma separated entries in R

Tags: r

I've got a data frame (df2) with two variables, Mood and PartOfTown, where Mood is a **multi-select** (ie any combination of options's allowed) question rating a person's happiness, and PartOfTown describes the geographical location.

The problem is that the centres code moods differently, with the centre in the northern part of town using NorthCode and the centre in the southern part using SouthCode (df1).

I'd like all the entries in the data set (df2) to be recoded to SouthCode, so that I end up with a data set like df3. I'd like a general solution, because there might be new entries with new combinations currently not featuring in the data set. Any thoughts on it would be much appreciated.

Centre codes and definitions for moods:

```
df1 <- data.frame(NorthCode=c(4,5,6,7,99),NorthDef=c("happy","sad","tired","energetic","other"),SouthCode=c(7,8,9,5,99),SouthDef=c("happy","sad","tired","energetic","other"))
```

Starting point:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Mood=c("4","5","6","7","4,5","5,6,99","99","7","8","9","5","7,8","8,5,99","99"),Region=c("north","north","north","north","north","north","north","south","south","south","south","south","south","south"))
```

Desired outcome:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Mood=c("7","8","9","5","7,8","8,9,99","99","7","8","9","5","7,8","8,5,99","99"),PartofTown=c("north","north","north","north","north","north","north","south","south","south","south","south","south","south"))
```

Current attempt: tried to start of by splitting the entries but couldn't get it to work.

```
unlist(strsplit(df2$Mood, ","))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path with strsplit, but you need to add stringsAsFactors = F to as.data.frame() to make sure that Mood is a character vector, not a factor.
After that you can keep the separated elements as a list and match the old codes with the new ones with lapply().

```
df1 <- 
  data.frame(NorthCode=c(4,5,6,7,99),
             NorthDef=c("happy","sad","tired","energetic","other"),
             SouthCode=c(7,8,9,5,99),
             SouthDef=c("happy","sad","tired","energetic","other"), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- 
  data.frame(Mood=c("4","5","6","7","4,5","5,6,99","99","7","8","9","5","7,8","8,5,99","99"),
             Region=c("north","north","north","north","north","north","north","south","south","south","south"    ,"south","south","south"), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)

df3 <- 
  data.frame(Mood=c("7","8","9","5","7,8","8,9,99","99","7","8","9","5","7,8","8,5,99","99"),
             PartofTown=c("north","north","north","north","north","north","north","south","south","south","south"   ,"south","south","south"),
             stringsAsFactors = F)

# Split the Moods into separate values
splitCodes <- strsplit(df2$Mood, ",")
# Add the Region as the name of each element in the new list
names(splitCodes) <- df2$Region

# Recode the values by matching the north values to the south values
recoded <- 
  lapply(
    seq_along(splitCodes),
    function(x){
      ifelse(rep(names(splitCodes[x]) == "north", length(splitCodes[[x]])),
             df1$SouthCode[match(splitCodes[[x]], df1$NorthCode)],
             splitCodes[[x]])
    }
  )

# Add the recoded values back to df2
df2$recoded <- 
  sapply(recoded,
         paste,
         collapse = ",")

# Check if the recoded values match your desired values    
identical(df2$recoded, df3$Mood)
```